# lodash.debounce search in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce a search in react using lodash, debounce.

But when ever its run I'm receiving a type error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'debounce' of undefined`

I have tried moving it around in the code but can't understand why it isn't working

I started off by importing it

`import { _, debounce } from 'lodash'`

I have an input as following

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.query}
    onChange={(e) => {this.updateQuery(e.target.value)}}
    placeholder="Search by title or author"
/>
```

Connected to this function

```
updateQuery = (query) => {
    _.debounce(() => query(this.setState({ query }), 500))
    this.onBookSearch(query)
}
```

Does anyone understand why this is?

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually have `lodash` in your node_modules. Did you forget to `npm install --save lodash`?

Comment: Hi, yes I do have it. Thanks for checking. The solution below worked

Comment: could you explain what does mean `query( this.setState()..), 500)` in a body of debounce function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your import is the problem. You probably want to import the `_` as default:

```
import _, {debounce} from 'lodash';
```

Also you're not using the extracted function:

```
updateQuery = (query) => {
  debounce(() => query(this.setState({ query }), 500))
  this.onBookSearch(query)
}
```

Since you're extracting `{debounce}` in the import you can use it directly.

Comment: could you explain what does mean `query( this.setState()..), 500)` in a body of debounce function?